# Unable to find style '' in skin 'DarkSkin' Layout

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

Unity editor script is throwing this warning,

> Unable to find style '' in skin 'DarkSkin' Layout

...and causing the styles on the editor to 'break'.

### The editor script:

```cs
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ONCCK.PlayerModel
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(PlayerModelMaker))]
    public class PlayerModelMakerEditor : Editor
    {
        private string _playerModelName;
        private string _playerModelDescription;

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            PlayerModelMaker instance = (PlayerModelMaker)target;

            if (instance.PlayerModel == null)
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Player model reference is null.", MessageType.Error);

            if (instance.HeadReference == null || instance.RightHandReference == null || instance.LeftHandReference == null)
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Player model maker is not set up correctly!", MessageType.Error);

            // Descriptor
            EditorGUILayout.TextField("Player model name", _playerModelName);
            EditorGUILayout.TextArea("Player model description", _playerModelDescription); // Line 24. This is throwing the warning.

            base.OnInspectorGUI();

            EditorGUILayout.Space();

            // Buttons

            if (GUILayout.Button("Create avatar"))
                instance.Setup();

            if (GUILayout.Button("Align hands"))
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

### The console output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TextArea](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.TextArea.html) doesn't have a label parameter. You can do something like

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("Player model description");
_playerModelDescription = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(_playerModelDescription);
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Comment: In general you should go over to use `using(new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope){ ... }` it helps to keep the overview where scopes begin and end and to not forget closing one ;)